# In Mongo, Increment and return value -- possible in 1 call?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In Mongo, is it possible to increase and get the result of the increment?

`collection.update({id: doc_id}, {$inc: {view_count: 1}});`

I tried to output the result of that statement (in node) and I got the following:

```
 { _id: 1,
  _state: undefined,
  _result: undefined,
  _subscribers: [] }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/). Add the `new:true` `option`.

According to the docs:

> The findAndModify command modifies and returns a single document. By default, the returned document does not include the modifications made on the update. To return the document with the modifications made on the update, use the new option.

You could do the following:

```
db.collection.findAndModify(
    query:  {_id: doc_id},
    update: { $inc: { view_count :1 } },
    new: true,
)
```

Comment: `findAndModify` does the job indeed!

Comment: For me `myCol.find({}).count())` is 2 but findAndModify prints undefined even using `new: true`.

var _ret = myCol.findAndModify({
  query: { _id: "userid"},
  update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
  new: true
 }
);
console.log('_ret: ',_ret);

Comment: For use in the Mongo shell try: `db.runCommand({ findAndModify: "collection", ... })`. For Mongoose use [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) or [findByIdAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Answer (score 1):

If you can´t find the **findAndModify** method to use on your collection,you can use the **findOneAndUpdate** method.

Here is how to use:

The following code finds the first document where name : R. Stiles and increments the score by 5:

```
const result = await db.grades.findOneAndUpdate(
   { "name" : "R. Stiles" }, //also you can search for id
   { $inc: { "points" : 5 } }
)
```

The code returns the original document before the update inside the "value" propety:

```
{ _id: 6319, name: "R. Stiles", "points" : 0,... } // result.value returns document before update, but in the db it changued
```

If you want get the document uploaded, you has to set "returnNewDocument" to true, so the operation would return the updated document instead.

I hope it works for you.

source: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/